# Mounting a directory containing multiple hard drive mount points using NFS

Tags: linux, nfs, network-share, nfsclient

I have 4 hard drivers mounted in a directory:

```
/dev/sda1        11T   62M   11T   1% /all-hdds/hdd1                                                    │ 36 #MpiParams=ports=#-#
/dev/sdb1        11T   62M   11T   1% /all-hdds/hdd2                                                    │ 37 #PluginDir=
/dev/sdc1        11T   62M   11T   1% /all-hdds/hdd3                                                    │ 38 #PlugStackConfig=
/dev/sdd1        11T   62M   11T   1% /all-hdds/hdd4
```

Is it possible to export `all-hdds` as a single NFS point and mount it on other clients? I tried it and I can see all the `hdd1`, `hdd2`, etc directories on the client side but when I create files inside them they don't show up on the host so I think maybe I'm hitting some sort of limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that `/all-hdds` itself is mounted from `/dev/sde1`.

When `/all-hdds/hdd1` is not mounted, `/all-hdds` (on sde1) still has a directory `/hdd1`, which is empty. When you mount sda1, you mounted the root of the filesystem in sda1 onto `/all-hdds/hdd1`.

But when you export `/all-hdds/hdd1` over NFS, it's confined only to the filesystem on `/dev/sde1`. So if on the client you mounted `/all-hdds` onto e.g. `/client-mountpoint` and then created a file `/client-mountpoint/hdd1/test`, what actually happens is that the file `/hdd1/test` is created on the filesystem `/all-hdds`, stored on `/dev/sde1`.

Of course, you don't see that file, because it is hidden by the filesystem on sda1, mounted onto `/all-hdds/hdd1`.

What this means is that you need to export all the filesystems, and explicitly tell the server that you want to export them as a tree.

That entails setting `fsid=0` mount option on the root of the exported tree, and setting the `nohide` option on the sub-exports.

The full guide is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo) (the installation part is Ubuntu-specific, the export part isn't).

Do note that this will mean that the client mounts `yoursever:/` rather than `yourserver:/all-hdds` - NFSv4 only has one root.